# Resolver does not report correct locale

Tags: magento2, multistore, locale, magento2.2.4

I have a very strange problem where the `Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver` does not return the correct locale for the current store view.

I have setup a store with two separate store views which have locales set to English and Swedish. I have also configured the stores to append the store code to the current URL.

```
class Example {
  /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface */
  private $storeManager;

  /** @var \Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver */
  private $resolver;

  public function __construct(StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
                              Resolver $resolver)
  {
     $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
     $this->resolver = $resolver;
  }

  /**
   * Get locale using resolver.
  **/
  public function getLocale()
  {
     return $this->resolver->getLocale();
  }

  /**
   * Get locale using storemanager
  **/
  public function getLocaleCode()
  {
     return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getLocaleCode();
  }
}
```

In the above code the `getLocale()` and `getLocaleCode()` always returns the locale of the default store view. I managed to solve this by using the `ScopeConfigInterface` like this:

```
class Example {
  /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface */
  private $scopeConfig;

  public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig)
  {
     $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
  }

  public function getLocale()
  {
     return
     $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
       'general/locale/code', 
       ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
       $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()
     );
  }
}
```

Even though the above works I really would like to know why the resolver returns the incorrect locale for the current store? I am thinking that this might be some kind of weird caching issue, I have tried all the following without any success:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply use the following to get the store locale

```
protected $_store;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Store\Api\Data\StoreInterface $store
) {
    $this->_store = $store;
}
```

and seems to work fine

```
$this->_store->getLocaleCode()
```

Comment: I have tried the above and it does not seem to work in this case. Are you running version  `2.2.4`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get current locale using storeManager Interface,

```
<?php
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}

public function getLocale() {
    return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getLocaleCode();
}
```

Comment: I have already tried that and its not working same problem as with the resolver, it reports the default stores locale.

Comment: Have you check using storemanager interface?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried using the `StoreManagerInterface` and it also returns the incorrect locale.

Comment: Are you really running version `2.2.4`?

Comment: I have checked its for 2.1.x

Comment: So then the problem perhaps are only related to version `2.2.4` which I am running.

Comment: MIght be possible for version issue.